# filtering in angularjs using or operator

Tags: angularjs, for-loop

i have a loop of an array Countries,example (this is in a multi select box)

`{Clicked : true, Name:USA,ID:1},
{Clicked :false, Name:China,ID:2},
{Clicked : true, Name:India,ID:4}`

when an item(Name value) is checked,the clicked value turns to true.So if i know all the values that are true can i loop through the countries array to get those values? 
once i got the true values i want to use the OR operator to pass only one id value and not all, example if its 1 || 4 || 2 then 4 should get passed.

what was attempted

```
$scope.FilterCountries=function(){

   var Clicked=true;
   for(var i=0;i<=$scope.model.Countries.length;i++)
     {
      Clicked= $scope.model.Countries.Clicked[i];
      var ID= Clicked || $scope.model.Countries.ID[i];
     }
  }
```

the above when i select a value,it sends back a different ID ,it adds its own value.

Comment: Its not clear to me what you want to do. But for example with ng-click in the view you can trigger a model change or start any logic you want in the controller.

Comment: @ChristianSteinmann calling the function is fine,it gets called,i have updated the question if that makes more sense

Answer (score 1):

I am still not sure what you want to do exactly but your code seems to be wrong. I put an example together.

If you mean Bitwise operations see here: [MDN Bitwise operations](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators)

I hope it helps.

```js
$scope = {
  model: {
    Countries: [{
      Clicked: true,
      ID: 1
    }, {
      Clicked: true,
      ID: 2
    }, {
      Clicked: true,
      ID: 4
    }]
  }
};

$scope.FilterCountries = function() {

  var result = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < $scope.model.Countries.length; i++) {

    if ($scope.model.Countries[i].Clicked === true) {
      //Bitwise operation ID: 1 and 2 and 4 would result in 7
      result = result | $scope.model.Countries[i].ID;
    }
  }

  return result;
};

document.write($scope.FilterCountries());
```

Later you can test if a country was checked by using the &-Operator

```js
(7 & 4) === 4; // true
```

Comment: thank you,that really helped,but i dont want to add all the numbers that are clicked together,i want it to get me the highest ID from all the IDs that were clicked.

Comment: thanks ,all i did was add a counter to results and it works like a charm

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.FilterCountries = function() {

 var result = 0;
 for (var i = 0; i < $scope.model.Countries.length; i++) {

  if ($scope.model.Countries[i].Clicked === true) {
  //Bitwise operation ID: 1 and 2 and 4 would result in 7
  result = result[i] | $scope.model.Countries[i].ID;
}
}
return result;
};
```